# ios - Setting the color of the moreNavigation when TabBarController is not the RootViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uicolor

I am trying to set the color of the `UINavigationBar` on a `UITabBarController`.
Now I know this can be done with:

```
UINavigationController* more = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
more.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

But my variation on the matter is that the UITabBarController is not the RootViewController, but another`UINavigationController` so this doesn't work for me like I want to.

How can I change the more `navBar` when `UITabBarController` is not the RootView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, where in the controller hierarchy is your tab bar controller? Is it the root view controller of the navigation controller? And from which controller do you want to make this color change?

Comment: It appears when i press a button and heads into another section. So it appears with a presentModalViewController.

Comment: So why doesn't the code you posted work? If you put that in the viewDidLoad of the controller in the first tab, it should work. It doesn't matter that the tab bar controller isn't the root view controller of the window.

Comment: Ah yeah maybe:-) I always put it in the appDelegate.

Comment: Cool that worked, if you want some points, then add it is an answer:-)